# How to display Sub Category depending on the selected Category

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a laravel project and I am using a `foreach` loop to show categories and subcategories. I have implemented the code and here it is:

```
<select id="category" class="form-control">
    @foreach($category as $categories)
        <option value="{{$categories->id}}">{{$categories->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>



<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control">
    @foreach($category as $categories)
        <optgroup label="{{$categories->id}}">
            @foreach($categories->subcategories as $subcategories)
                <option value="{{$subcategories->id}}">{{$subcategories->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </optgroup>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And here is my JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $optgroups = $('#subcategory > optgroup');

        $("#category").on("change",function(){
            var selectedVal = this.value;

            $('#subcategory').html($optgroups.filter('[label="'+selectedVal+'"]'));
            // $('#subcategory .dropdown-header li').html($optgroups.filter('[label="'+selectedVal+'"]'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

The thing is it works. In inspect element it works. But it does not change inside of the dropdown `select` tag (sub categories I mean).
What I have noticed is that there is a div with class `dropdown-menu open` and inside of it is a `ul` tag with class `dropdown-menu inner`. And finally inside of that `ul` tag, there are `li` tags. This is the reason why it wont change from the `select` tag view. And so these `li` tags display all the subcategories and does not filter it. These `li` tags are responsible for showing the items inside of the `select` tag. I am stuck here and I do not know how to filter them. The `li` tags have `span` tags with class name `text`.

So how can I filter these?

Comment: Can you show us a working fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1):

It won't change, because your categories are in the server-side, but you are changing the code in the client-side, your code in the front-end doesn't know which sub-category belongs to which category.

To solve this you need to make ajax call to retrieve the sub-categories that belongs to the current active category, so you could do something like this:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $optgroups = $('#subcategory > optgroup');

        $("#category").on("change",function(){
            var selectedVal = this.value;

            // Retrieve all sub-categories of the current category
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/categories/" + selectedVal,
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(subCategories) {
                // Your API must return the sub-categories in Json format
                $.each(subCategories, function( index, category ) {
                    $('#subcategory').append("<optgroup label=" + category.id + ">
                            <option value='" + category.id + "'>" + category.name +"</option>
                        </optgroup>");
                });


            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I did not test the code above, so you could expect some bugs. But you should be able to improve it to suite your needs. Goodluck.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. The problem for me was the bootstrap select module which i placed. I did not notice it as it was inside of my main blade layout file. I have removed my JS which was responsible for initiating the select classes on all select tags. But thank you anyways. I found using foreach loop inside of blade much easier than playing with ajax. +1